# An answer which is completely quoted from a source

Tags: discussion, answers, attribution

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27652808/862351) to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652452/almost-always-decltypeauto/27652808#27652808) question was just a quote from the isocpp faq on that topic. IMO the quoted explanation completely answers the question. While I attributed and linked to it, what is the recommended thing to do in this situation?

Comment: Plagiarism is passing off work as your own. You didn't. Sometimes 'RTFM' is the answer to a question, but quoting the relevant section (and referencing it) is politer :). 
You did the right thing - quoting is fine, but attribution is important.

Comment: Do you feel bad for doing that? In this case make the answer community wiki so that you don't earn reputation thanks to someone else's explanation (although I'm not saying that it would be wrong to get the reputation).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Finding the correct part of a big document can be difficult. Showing a concise answer and showing exactly where your answer comes from seems correct to me. In many endeavours quoting a small part of a document, with the correct acknowledgement, is considered fair use and not plagiarism.

I would say it was a good answer.

Comment: Attributed quoting is never plagiarism.  Even if it is the entire document.  Regardless of "fair use", plagiarism refers to passing someone else's stuff off as your own: once attributed, it isn't plagiarism.