# Where are my points for Mortarboard badge on meta?

Tags: support, badges, daily-reputation-limit

I have just been awarded the *Mortarboard* badge on meta.stackoverflow.com. The badge description says *Earned at least 200 reputation (the daily maximum) in a single day*. But where are these points shown?

My answer to [An answer which is completely quoted from a source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281143/an-answer-which-is-completely-quoted-from-a-source) on meta has received some votes but as these votes are on Meta they do not give points. Is the description of the *Mortarboard* badge correct?

Comment: Although no reputation is visible on meta you can use one of the [reputation queries](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234414/158100) and switch it to use the [data from meta.so](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/203302/user-reputation-history?uid=546871#graph)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no points; just read it as *loads of upvotes*.

The badge is awarded when you'd have gotten enough points if there were any points. The same applies to [Epic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/42/epic) and [Legendary](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/43/legendary).